# В чём разница между using и on в join-запросах?

Tags: sql

Сабж в заголовке, т.е. равносильны ли запросы (если mysql рассматривать)

```
SELECT * FROM `tab1` RIGHT JOIN `tab` ON `table2`.`id` = `table1`.`id`
```

и

```
SELECT * FROM `tab1` RIGHT JOIN `tab2` USING(`id`)
```

если нет, то какой лучше и в чём различие?

Comment: нет отличия. только в ON можно указывать любое соответствие (разные имена колонок), а в UNSING имена полей должны полностью совпадать

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ответ?

Comment: @andreycha я просто случайно нашел на enSO подобный вопрос и решил немного расширить ответ

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**USING (column_name(s))**, по сути, является синтаксическим сахарочком над **ON**. Согласно **[докам](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/JOIN.html)** — служит для указания списка столбцов, которые должны существовать **в обеих** таблицах.

Такое выражение **USING**, как:

```
A LEFT JOIN B USING (C1, C2, C3, ...)
```

семантически идентично выражению **ON**:

```
A.C1 = B.C1 AND A.C2 = B.C2 AND A.C3 = B.C3,...
```

В то время как **ON** можно "склеить" столбцы с различными именами.

Но с **ON** можно проделать операций чуть больше, например можно присоединить не только колонку, но и набор колонок или даже целое условие, пример:

```
SELECT * FROM world.City JOIN world.Country ON (City.CountryCode = Country.Code) WHERE ...
```

---

#### Дополнительно

**USING** — при перечислении полей в запросе не обязательно указывать префикс:

```
SELECT film.title, film_id  // # film_id указан без префикса
FROM film
JOIN film_actor USING (film_id)
WHERE ...
```

Тоже самое с **ON**:

```
SELECT film.title, film.film_id // # film.film_id обязателен префикс
FROM film
JOIN film_actor ON (film.film_id = film_actor.film_id)
WHERE ...
```

Если не перечислять поля явно, а использовать **`select *`** для соединения столбцов, то в результирующем наборе при **ON** колонка "всплывёт" дважды, в то время как с `USING` — только раз:

```
mysql>  create table t(i int);
        insert t select 1;
        create table t2 select*from t;

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.11 sec)

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.19 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from t join t2 on t.i = t2.i;
+------+------+
|    i |    i |
+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |
+------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from t join t2 using(i);
+------+
|    i |
+------+
|    1 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

---

<sub>инфа позаимствована на enSO [MySQL ON vs USING?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11367066/6104996)</sub>

Comment: *с **ON** можно проделать операций чуть больше, например можно присоединить не только колонку, но и набор колонок или даже целое условие* Думаю, есть смысл привести три примера - первый уже есть (неодноимёные поля), во втором использовать связывание не по равенству (типа `ON t1.field > t2.field)`, а в третьем использовать выражения (скажем, `ON t1.date - INTERVAL 1 DAYS <= DATE(t2.datetime))`